# How to unjam garbage disposal

Tags: garbage-disposal

Garbage disposal stopped today after I tossed some coffee grounds into it.  It makes a nice hum when you turn the power on of the motor trying to run, but nothing spins.  I've tried the reset button at the bottom to no luck.  I've fished around in there and there doesn't appear to be anything (like a spoon or whatnot) blocking it.

Any way to get it going?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

disposals usually come with a small hex wrench that fits in to the bottom of disposal. This lets you move the shaft of the motor back and forth to loosen up whatever it stopping it. If you can't find yours, you can pick one up at a hardware store or plumbing supply shop.

Comment: Also, may sound obvious, but be absolutely sure power is turned off. Never push the reset button or on/off switch with the hex wrench inserted into the shaft socket.

Comment: OMG that would hurt, I can't imagine someone doing that....

Comment: Trust me, it happens!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if the hex wrench at the center of the bottom of the unit moves freely and the disposal wont start then look for a little reset button on the unit near the power supply. Find it, press it and try again. everything should be fine now.

Comment: -1 for not having read the part where I said that I tried the reset button.